# How can I make BitMeterOS run at startup? Which .exe should I place in the Startup Folder?

Tags: windows-10

I've installed BitMeter OS on my Windows 10 PC and I'd like to have it run at startup.

I've checked the FAQs and instructions and I'm not sure which .exe is the one I need to put in the Startup folder.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitMeter OS comes with a `daemon` service/application, and you then browse to `localhost:2605/index.html` to see the interface.

I don't have BitMeter installed, but you want to look for something with `daemon` in the name. Alternatively, you may have a service called `BitMeterWebService`.

Comment: Thanks.  I added a shortcut to BitMeterWebService.exe to Startup in the Windows menu and it works perfectly.

Comment: @spikey_richie you mention the portable version. I am unable to find this. Do you mind sharing a link?

Comment: @SamOT I can't find it now, maybe I dreamt it... I'll update the answer.